# fullPage.js scrollOverflow:true not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullPage.js on my site and I have a section(Studio) where I have content that needs a normal scrolling. Now the problem is I cannot achieve that normal scrolling on that section. When I scroll on it, it automatically moves to the next section and skips the content inside fully.

I have read a few posts around S.O and tried the different answers but none works so far.

Here's a link to my site:
http://sabirmb.com/Parallax

Basically I set `scrollOverflow: true;` to allow for scrolling but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It is working on [the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html). You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Alvaro Yes. I did fix it yesterday. The problem was that I didn't make use of afterLoad and onLeave and instead wrote my code inside the fullPage.js itself which created some conflicts.

Comment: @Alvaro what is the best way to push extra content below the bottom of the screen that can then be scrolled to? For example, in the link you provided above, if there is no text but images, and these images need to be pushed below the fold. Does this make sense?

Comment: It works with images too. Just add to the section and check it yourself.

Comment: @Alvaro thanks! i know it works with images, but if there aren't any `p` tags but i want to push the image 'below the fold' so to speak i can't push it down as `margin-top`, `top` on the image then prevents the image from being pushed down and the section still scrollable. It is probably best if i make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Alvaro see jsfiddle here - may make it clearer what i mean - https://jsfiddle.net/aez2uk59/ - if you remove`top: 475px` from `.phone-two` you will see it works again as normal. Do you know what i mean?